# Find Sum by using LINQ Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a SQL table where I get multiple records. But I want to sum of `[Value]` group by `Sales and Collection`

```
ExecutiveName   ClientName  2017-01-21  2017-01-22  2017-01-24  ValueofGoal  GoalType
Admin           Omelettes   10000       NULL        NULL        50000        Collection
Admin           Omelettes   10000       NULL        NULL        120000       Sales
Admin           Vijay       NULL        NULL        10000       50000        Collection
Admin           Vijay       NULL        NULL        10000       120000       Sales
Admin           Sujeet      NULL        10000       NULL        50000        Collection
Admin           Sujeet      NULL        10000       NULL        120000       Sales
```

Above, this is my actual table, where I want total of `ValueofGoal` basis of `Collection and Sales` and Grand total of `ValueOfGoal` column

Just like:

```
 Sales       : 360000 
 Collection  : 150000
 Total       : 510000
```

If anyone know how I can do that by using a lambda expression, please provide me a solution

Comment: Did you try to do it yourself?

Comment: `var data = db.yourTable.GroupBy(x => x.GoalType).Select(x => new { Goal = x.Key, Total = x.Sum(y => y.ValueofGoal ) });`

Comment: A database table is not an actual object in C#. Where is your code showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
.GroupBy(x => x.GlobalType)
    .Select(n => n.Sum(m => m.ValueofGoal));
```

This block of code will group by the GlobalType and then sum the all values according to the groupby and will return the sum of each.

Comment: This is wrong, What is count here? how it gives sum of `ValueofGoal  `

Comment: You should really add a little more to this. A description or explanation of the logic or something more than just a naked code reply.

Comment: Ok, I added the description as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var list = dbContext.YourModel.GroupBy(x=>x.GoalType)
    .Select(x=>new {
        GoalType=x.Key,
        ValueOfGoal=x.Sum(y=>y.ValueofGoal)
    }).ToList();
```